# Getting children and grand children for a parent in Hive

Tags: impala

I have a hierarchy Hive table with two columns, Parent and Child.
I need to get the list of all descendants associated with the parent records. Please note that
recursive SQL is not supported in Hive/Imapala.

```
Source Table
+----+-----------+
| Parent | Child |
+----+-----------+
|  a     |     b |
|  b     |     c |
|  c     |     d |
|  d     |     e |
|  e     |     f |
|  f     |     x |
+----+-----------+

Expected Result:
+----+-----------+
| Parent | Child |
+----+-----------+
|  a     |     b |  // As b is the child of a, all the descendants of b 
|  a     |     c |  // are also descendants of a. 
|  a     |     d |
|  a     |     e |
|  a     |     f |
|  a     |     x |
|  b     |     c |  // As c is the child of b, all the descendants of c 
|  b     |     d |  // are also descendants of b.
|  b     |     e |
|  b     |     f |
|  b     |     x |
|  c     |     d |
|  c     |     e |
|  c     |     f |
|  c     |     x |
|  d     |     e |
|  d     |     f |
|  d     |     x |
|  e     |     f |
|  e     |     x |
|  f     |     x |
+----+-----------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: If your SQL dialect does not support _declarative_ recursion, then you have to implement some kind of _applicative_ iterative processing -- and here "applicative" means "outside of SQL". Since you mention Impala then you have no easy access to HPL/SQL (shipped with Hive 2) so you are stuck with java code running JDBC statements.

Comment: And of course, the algorithm involves running a series of `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ... ` until the inserted count is zero. The Hive JDBC driver will not return the inserted count, which makes it extra fun. Don't know about the Impala driver though.